# How to make my custom buttons shuffle along the x-axis

Tags: objective-c

Why is it when I try to animate my custom cup buttons they are moving along the x-axis and y-axis even though I have the y-axis fixed? I'm using the array above to grab a random button and set it to `randomCup1` and so on. I then want to use `randomCup1` to move `_cupButton1` to that location, and the same for the rest.

When I run the code, the cups shuffle but they are moving very weirdly. Any tips would be much appreciated!

```
(void)shuffleCups{
    _numberOfTimesShuffled++;
    if(_numberOfTimesShuffled > 4){
        _cupButton1.canBeClicked = true;
        _cupButton2.canBeClicked = true;
        _cupButton3.canBeClicked = true;
        return;
    }

    else{
        NSMutableArray *cupButtonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [cupButtonsArray addObject:_cupButton1];
        [cupButtonsArray addObject:_cupButton2];
        [cupButtonsArray addObject:_cupButton3];

        int random1 =  arc4random() % [cupButtonsArray count];
        CupButton *randomCup1 = [cupButtonsArray objectAtIndex:random1];
        [cupButtonsArray removeObjectAtIndex:random1];

        NSLog(@"This is random 1 %d", random1);

        int random2 = arc4random() % [cupButtonsArray count];
        CupButton *randomCup2 = [cupButtonsArray objectAtIndex:random2];
        [cupButtonsArray removeObjectAtIndex:random2];

        NSLog(@"This is random 2 %d", random2);

        CupButton *randomCup3 = [cupButtonsArray objectAtIndex:0];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay:0.1
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:^{
                             [_cupButton1 setCenter:CGPointMake(randomCup2.frame.origin.x, _cupButton1.frame.origin.y)];

                         }completion:^(BOOL finshed){
                             //[self shuffleCups];
                         }];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay:0.1
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:^{
                             [_cupButton2 setCenter:CGPointMake(randomCup3.frame.origin.x, _cupButton1.frame.origin.y)];

                         }completion:^(BOOL finshed){
                             //[self shuffleCups];
                         }];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay:0.1
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:^{
                             [_cupButton3 setCenter:CGPointMake(randomCup1.frame.origin.x, _cupButton1.frame.origin.y)];

                         }completion:^(BOOL finshed){
                             [self shuffleCups];
                         }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the y value of the center of the button to the origin y value which is in the upper left of the view. If you don't want it to move vertically, you should set the y value to _cupButton1.center.y

Also, there is a logic error in your version. Both `_cupButtonX` and `randomCupX` are referencing the same buttons. This means that you could move a button and then use it for reference later with another button. For example, if `_cupButton1` were assigned to `_randomCup2` and `_cupButton2` were assigned to `_randomCup1`. Fist, `_cupButton1` would be moved to where `_cupButton2` was. Then `_cupButton2` would be kept at the same spot because that is where `_cupButton1` is now.

Here is a cleaner (at least in my opinion) version of your code that doesn't have the logic error:

```
- (void)shuffleCups
{
    _numberOfTimesShuffled++;
    if (_numberOfTimesShuffled > 4) {
        _cupButton1.canBeClicked = true;
        _cupButton2.canBeClicked = true;
        _cupButton3.canBeClicked = true;
        return;
    }
    else {
        // You can create arrays with the short-hand @[]
        // (the mutable copy surrounding it makes it mutable)
        NSMutableArray *cupButtonsArray = [@[
            _cupButton1,
            _cupButton2,
            _cupButton3
        ] mutableCopy];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
            delay:0.1
            options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
            animations:^{
                // Storing the points to move to instead of a reference
                // to the buttons themselves
                CGPoint newPoints[3];
                // Use NSUInteger instead of int because that is what NSArray
                // uses as its index type
                for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % cupButtonsArray.count;
                    // You can use brackets as a short-hand on NSArrays instead
                    // of objectAtIndex:
                    newPoints[i] = [cupButtonsArray[randomIndex] center];
                    [cupButtonsArray removeObjectAtIndex:randomIndex];
                }

                // You can animate multiple changes all in one animtation block
                [_cupButton1 setCenter:newPoints[0]];
                [_cupButton2 setCenter:newPoints[1]];
                [_cupButton3 setCenter:newPoints[2]];
             }
             completion:nil
        ];
    }
}
```

Not a massive change, but cleaning up small bits of code has a big impact when applied to a whole codebase.

Comment: Wow yeah that worked, thanks! So if i want the cup to move exactly where the randomCup is I need to also make the randomCup.center.x?

Comment: Or what do I need to do, so my cups will shift to the new random position? Does my logic seem ok? Thanks for the help

Comment: There is a lot you can do to clean up your code but the logic seems sound. I will update my above answer with a cleaned up code so that you get an idea of what cleaner code looks like.

Comment: Ok I updated it. I brought a little bit of my personal style into it but you get the idea. Also, I did think of a logic problem with your original code as described in my edit.

Comment: Ran what you did and it works perfect, impressive. Would you mind explaining how [_cupButton1 setCenter:newPoints[0]]; is using only one point when it usually asks for two parameters. Also what [cupButtonsArray[randomIndex] center] is doing. I think it is grabbing the locations of the cup and storing them in newPoints.

Comment: Sure, setCenter actually only takes one parameters, a CGPoint. A CGPoint is made up of two coordinates which I think is why you are confused. You were previously using `CGPointMake` which takes the two parameters and returns a CGPoint that you were then passing into `setCenter`. I am storing the entire CGPoint in the array.

Comment: As for the second part, I can breakdown the statement into two parts that I think will make it more clear to you: `UIButton *button = cupButtonsArray[randomIndex]; newPoints[i] = [button center];` You can use brackets on an NSArray as a shorthand for `objectAtIndex:`